# How to sort this object by name in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My client needs an angular js app, the app is based on an api, of an app that's already running.
one of the apis, returns a json structured like this:

```
{  
   "groups":{  
      "60":{  
         "name":"History"
      },
      "74":{  
         "name":"Discover our offers"
      },
      "109":{  
         "name":"Relaxing"
      }
   }
}
```

so we fetched the data on a controller this way:

```
  $http({method: 'GET', url: restUrl}).
      then(function(response)
      {
          $scope.poi_groups = response.data.groups;
      });
```

and display it on the view:

```
<ul class="content-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in poi_groups">
        <div><a ng-href="/poi/data/{{ key }}">{{ value.name }}</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I've been struggling with is ordering the items by name, right now its being displayed exactly the way its returned on the json.
How can I do something like:

```
(...)
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in poi_groups | orderBy: value.name">
(...)
```

Comment: Try to add quotes: `orderBy: 'value.name'`

Comment: objects have no order and `orderBy` is for arrays as per docs. Will need to map to array

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375006/angular-orderby-object-possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure isn't appropriate for angularjs, either :

1. Do it yourself in the .then method
2. Write your own filter
3. Map your object in a new one in the .then method to make it look like this :

   [{
       value:'60', 
       name:'History'
   }, {
       ....
   }]

Then you can use angular filtering.

Comment: ended up doing this 
        for(var index in $scope.poi_groups)
        {
            map_groups_to_array.push(
                {
                    index: index,
                    name: $scope.poi_groups[index].name
                });
        };

Comment: This solution is the one that i use because i leave the request part in angular services that take the responsability of call the http request and format data as the controllers need. Transform timestamp to date for instance to not have any problem with all date widgets, or just transform the whole object because his structure does not fit for angular.

Answer (score 0):

use ngRepeat [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Use filter like **`orderBy: 'name'`**

```
 <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in poi_groups| orderBy:'name'">
```

and

```
 <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in poi_groups| orderBy:'name': -1">
```

for DESC

if you make plnk we can check it out

Comment: for some reason the filter does nothing

Comment: @user3531149 because data is not an array and needs to be mapped to array in controller or custom filter to be able to be sorted. Docs for `orderBy` clearly state it is for array