# orderBy not filtering properly with $index

Tags: angularjs

[image]I am relatively new to using AngularJs and I am having trouble understanding/ getting orderBy to work. I am familiar that by using it with an ng-repeat on an array you can sort the array... however when I try and implement it while using the track by $index.. I know that filtering has to come before tracking but I still cant get it to work. On a side note... I have an Object of Objects which I thought still might work by determining the keys in the objects.

**html**

```
<table id="data-sources-table" class="table drag-drop header-fixed">
        <tbody ng-repeat="(field, profile) in currentSample.dsProfile | orderBy:'[display-name]' track by $index">
            <tr ng-style="$index % 2 === 0 && {'background-color': '#ffffff'} ||
                          $index % 2 === 1 && {'background-color': '#f9f9f9'}">
                <td>
                    <span class="btn-property"
                          uib-tooltip="{{field}}"
                          tooltip-placement="right">
                        <b>{{profile["display-name"]}}</b>
```

Comment: remove `[]` .... `orderBy:'display-name'`

Comment: that didn't work :(

Comment: Based on ng-repeat syntax `(field, profile) in...` looks like you aren't using array at all but are using object. Show sample data structure. Note that objects can't be ordered. A demo in plunker would help

Comment: updated with object... I am pretty much trying to do an ngrepeat on dsProfile key name... I have been working on a plunkr with no luck

Comment: You can't sort an object in javascript. What is `currentSample`? I can't really tell what you re needing.

Comment: $scope.currentSample = $scope.model.dataSamples[$scope.currentSampleIndex];

Comment: Ok...so it is an object. What do you expect to order? If you need to order the property keys will need to make array of those by iterating object yourself in controller

Comment: Alphabetical order of Key Names

Comment: You need to make an array of them

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375006/angular-orderby-object-possible

Comment: okay, I created a Custom Filter, what would be the correct syntax to get my desired results? The filter is named 'orderByObject'